Formally defining the expectation with respect to a Gaussian process
I've been reading some papers recently on deep neural networks and the neural tangent kernel, and one paper introduces an expression that gets repeated a lot in citing papers:
$$
\Sigma^{(\ell+1)}(x, x') = \mathbb{\beta^2} + \mathbb{E}_{f\sim\mathcal{GP}(0,\Sigma^{(\ell)})}\left[\sigma(f(x))^T\sigma(f(x'))\right]
$$
The authors of the original paper note that what they mean by this is really that we sample $f(x), f(x')$ from a multivariate Gaussian with covariance matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma^{(\ell)}(x, x) & \Sigma^{(\ell)}(x, x') \\ \Sigma^{(\ell)}(x, x')^T & \Sigma^{(\ell)}(x', x')\end{bmatrix}$. Derivative works don't seem to take the same care.
I just wanted to double check that, there really isn't a "nice" or "useful" way of formally defining $\mathbb{E}_{f\sim \mathcal{GP}}[\mathcal{L}(f)]$ for some cost functional $\mathcal{L}$ right? My knowledge on GPs is limited, however I do recall learning that it's extremely difficult to define any sort of useful Borel measure on a space of functions. I know of the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem and that it allows us to define a measure on some sort of measurable function space, but, is that theory rich enough to give us a meaningful definition of $\mathbb{E}_{f\sim\mathcal{GP}}$?

If $\mathcal L$ is continuous and the gaussian process is continuous, then there is no issue.

@Andrew for clarity, $\mathcal{L}$ continuous in what space?

$\mathcal L$ doesn't really need to be continuous, measurable is good enough.

@Andrew I guess my question is more qualitative than quantitative. Sure, I guess we could define the expectation as an integral wrt some measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with the product $\sigma$-algebra, but I've never really seen this definition used anywhere before, and I'm not sure if it's a fruitful definition; does this expectation converge for reasonable $\mathcal{L}$? Are reasonable $\mathcal{L}$, like evaluation functionals, even measurable?

This Mathoverflow question seems to imply that evaluation functionals would not be measurable under any $\sigma$-algebra: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1388/is-there-a-natural-measures-on-the-space-of-measurable-functions

When your process is continuous, or even only right or left continuous, there is no issue.

@Andrew could you walk through the details of an example in an answer? I'd be curious how you'd go about calculating this expectation for a GP with say an RBF kernel.

Im not sure what the details of your situation are, but the general point is this. If you have a process, that is, a collection of random variables $(X_t)_t$, then one endows $\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ with $\sigma(X_t:t\geq 0)$. This $\sigma$-algebra is useless in general, as only sets which depend on a countable number of times are measurable. If $X$ is a continuous process, then this $\sigma$-algebra is all one needs because continuous processes are determined by their values at rational times. And then any reasonable functional on $C([0,\infty))$ should be measurable.

Ah okay I see, thanks. Robert Aumann's result in the MO question I linked says $[0, 1]^{[0, 1]}$ admits no $\sigma$-algebras for which the evaluation functionals are measurable. I'm not sure if this result holds in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ or if continuity changes the situation but I'd wager a guess that your definition still doesn't allow us to evaluate the expression for $\Sigma^{(\ell+1)}$. Am I wrong?

What do you mean by evaluation functional?

The map $e_x(f) := f(x)$. The functional in $\Sigma^{(\ell+1)}$ can be written in terms of these, hence my skepticism.

This map is certainly measurable, continuity or not. The $\sigma$-algebra one uses is $\sigma(X_t:t\geq 0)$. In other words, $X_t$ is measurable for every $t$.

Huh really? That squares with the MO post? I figured you could descend $\sigma(X_t\ :\ t\ge 0)$ to a sigma algebra on $[0, 1]^{[0, 1]}$ and get a contradiction but maybe my intuition is off and I need to just write it out and see.

Oh I might have overlooked that Aumann's result is about sigma-algebras on the space of Borel measurable functions on the unit interval, and not on $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$. My mistake!

Put $I=[0,1]$. One equips $I^I$ with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form ${x:x_{t_i}\in B_i}$ for times $t_1,\dots t_n$ and $B_i\subset I$ are Borel sets. You can check that a process $X$ is measurable with respect to this $\sigma$ algebra if and only if $X_t$ are measurable for every $t$.
